# Value for event.which for keyup event is 0 when ESC is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have this jQuery code in my ASP.Net master page

```
    jQuery(document).keypress(function(event) {
        alert('keypress() called. e.which = ' + event.which);
        if (event.which == 27) {
            jQuery(this).trigger('escapeKeyPressed');
        }
    });
```

After the page has completed loading, I press ESC and the alert message is 'keypress() called. e.which = 0'.  I have understood from my research that the value should be 27.

This jQuery is a small portion of code I have to test programmatically simulating the ESC key being pressed.  I am doing this to try and automatically stop all animated gif's from animating when a page is loaded. So my ultimate goal is to properly trigger an event to get the images to stop animating.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use event.keyCode instead

```
if(event.keyCode == 27) {
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu7wz/

Comment: Yes, `which` is good for visible characters, but `keyCode` is used for "control keys".

Comment: `which` returns `27` too, maybe this needs to be updated?